# `dplyr`'s `summarize_all()` by some condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with an ID column and multiple columns that I want to summarize. In each of the columns (which are mutually exclusive), I want to count rows that match "a", "b", or either.

```
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     id col1  col2  col3
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 NA    b     NA
2     2 NA    b     NA
3     3 NA    NA    a
4     4 b     NA    NA
5     5 a     NA    NA
```

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
> df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarize_all(a = nrow(. %>% filter(. == "a"),
                  b = nrow(. %>% filter(. == "b"),
                  x = nrow(!is.na(.))
Error: Can't create call to non-callable object
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Am I taking the right approach? I'm trying to get something that looks like this:

```
var   a  b  x
-------------
col1  1  1  2
col2  0  2  2
col3  1  0  1
```

Comment: Please add your expected output. It's not clear if rows are mutually exclusive how "both" can be matched.

Comment: Sorry, I meant either, rather than both. My intended output is a count of each value for each column, i.e. `col1`: 1 `a` and 1 `b`, `col2`: 2 `b`s, `col3`: 1 a

Comment: I second @H1 request to include your expected output. It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Please edit your question to include the expected output for the sample data you show.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a problem for summarize_all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -id) %>%
  group_by(key, value) %>%
  count %>%
  filter(!is.na(value))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   key, value [4]
  key   value     n
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 col1  a         1
2 col1  b         1
3 col2  b         2
4 col3  a         1
```

If you want the tabular result edited into your question you can do:

```
df %>%
  gather(key, value, -id) %>%
  group_by(key, value) %>%
  count %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(x = sum(n)) %>%
  spread(value, n, fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   key [3]
  key       x     a     b
  <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 col1      2     1     1
2 col2      2     0     2
3 col3      1     1     0
```

Comment: It looks so simple now. I can't believe I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 1):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
 df %>%
  gather(var, letters, -id, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  add_count(var, letters, name = "n_letters") %>%
  add_count(var, name = "n_all") %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  distinct()

  var   letters n_letters n_all
  <chr> <chr>       <int> <int>
1 col1  b               1     2
2 col1  a               1     2
3 col2  b               2     2
4 col3  a               1     1
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 gather(var, letters, -id, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
 add_count(var, letters, name = "n_letters") %>%
 add_count(var, name = "all") %>%
 select(-id) %>%
 distinct() %>%
 spread(letters, n_letters, fill = 0)

  var   all     a     b
  <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 col1      2     1     1
2 col2      2     0     2
3 col3      1     1     0
```